# Django postgres order_by distinct on field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

We have a limitation for order_by/distinct fields.
From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct): "fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order"

Now here is the use case:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    is_vip = models.BooleanField()
    ...

class CourseEvent(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
```

The goal is to fetch the courses, ordered by nearest date but vip goes first.

The solution could look like this:

```
CourseEvent.objects.order_by('-course__is_vip', '-date',).distinct('course_id',).values_list('course')
```

But it causes an error since the limitation.

Yeah I understand why ordering is necessary when using distinct - we get the first row for each value of course_id so if we don't specify an order we would get some arbitrary row.
But what's the purpose of limiting order to the same field that we have distinct on?

If I change order_by to something like ('course_id', '-course__is_vip', 'date',) it would give me one row for course but the order of courses will have nothing in common with the goal.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation besides walking through the entire queryset and filtering it in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested query using `id__in`. In the inner query you single out the distinct events and in the outer query you custom-order them:

```
CourseEvent.objects.filter(
    id__in=CourseEvent.objects\
        .order_by('course_id', '-date').distinct('course_id')
).order_by('-course__is_vip', '-date')
```

From the docs on `distinct(*fields)`:

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.

Comment: Nope, that would give me courses ordered by course id, not by nearest date and vip flag.

Comment: And the second order_by won't help since we've already lost the information about date by making that distinct call

Comment: No, you haven't. There is no second `order_by`. You have all the latest records for each `course_id`. There is one order clause in each of the nested queries

Comment: Yeah but .order_by('course_id', '-course__is_vip', '-date') is absolutely same as .order_by('course_id',) since id's are unique. So we never had this information

Comment: No, `id` is unique for `CourseEvent`, `course_id` isn't! Multiple events can point to the same course. The `course__is_vip` is superfluous though, I'll admit. Updated, had deleted the wrong items in the outer order_by

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Looks like this should work. Gonna test now. Thanks!